# Use of sequence while adding and deleting from a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sequence

I am creating a table where I will add file name and many other fields. I used a fileid column to represent files in sequential order; i.e. first file to be uploaded should have fieldid 1, then the next file would have fileid 2 and so on. I used a sequence and trigger:

```
create sequence create_file_id start with 1 increment by 1 nocache;
```

The trigger is:

```
before insert on add_files_details
for each row
begin
select create_file_id.nextval into :new.file_id from dual;
end;
```

But, if any record/records is/are deleted from the table, then the sequence gets jumbled. So, I am thinking of using another sequence with a trigger to decrement the value of former sequence by the number of rows deleted. But I am stuck in implementing the trigger of this sequence.

Sequence:

```
create sequence del_file_id increment by -1 nocache;
```

Any way of achieving this?

Comment: There is probably some way of doing this but at best it will be a complex way to accomplish something whose value is doubtful and at worst will be buggy, slow, and unreliable.  Been there, done that, regretted it.  I strongly suggest you reconsider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can let the sequence do the *primary key* job and create a view of your base table, selecting

`rownum` as the column where you want to see numbers from 1 to N in sequential order:

```
SQL> create table your_table(
  2    tab_id number primary key,
  3    col    number
  4  )
  5  ;

Table created

SQL> create sequence gen_id;

Sequence created

SQL> create trigger TR_PK_your_table
  2  before insert on your_table
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.tab_id := gen_id.nextval; -- This kind of assignment is allowed in 11g  
  6  end;                             -- and higher, in version prior to 11g 
  7  /                                -- conventional select statement is used

Trigger created

SQL> insert into your_table(col)
  2  select level 
  3    from dual
  4  connect by level <=7;

7 rows inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select *
  2    from your_table;

    TAB_ID        COL
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          3
         4          4
         5          5
         6          6
         7          7

7 rows selected

SQL> create or replace view V_your_table
  2  as
  3  select tab_id
  4       , col
  5       , rownum as num
  6    from your_table
  7  ;

View created

SQL> select *
  2    from v_your_table;

    TAB_ID        COL        NUM
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          2          2
         3          3          3
         4          4          4
         5          5          5
         6          6          6
         7          7          7

7 rows selected

SQL> delete from your_table where tab_id in (3,5,6);

3 rows deleted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select *
  2    from your_table;

    TAB_ID        COL
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         4          4
         7          7

SQL> select *
  2    from v_your_table;

    TAB_ID        COL        NUM
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          2          2
         4          4          3
         7          7          4

SQL>
```

Comment: That is a really tricky yet simple solution. Thank you for pointing out this solution

Answer (score 5):

Read [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1133611000346070688) on why you wouldn't want to try and create a gapless sequence.

@Nicholas has a pretty good approach there, never thought of that before.

However, a couple of problems.

1. If using rownum in your view you would also have to include the ORDER BY statement on TAB_ID.
2. Using TAB_ID from the example; in a RAC system, there is no guarantee that you'll get the next available number, so ORDER BY may not help.

Expanding a little bit on the approach though, perhaps add in a DATE or TIMESTAMP column on the table and then use that in the ORDER BY. I haven't tested that approach.

Back to AskTom's point, is there a specific reason why you want a gapless sequence?

> what happens when a water pipe bursts in the room over the room the boxes are in and 50 of the boxes are completely and utterly damaged
>   beyond use.
>
> or someone crushes a box by accident.
>
> or - whatever
>
> it is not gapless in general. And it is not a system assigned, gap
>   free sequence either...

Comment: We are developing a document sharing site ,frontend is Java and backend is oracle pl/sql. So, whenver we want to add files , the id should be generated sequentially . But if file is deleted from this table, that entire row must be removed from this table and has to be inserted on another table,named deleted files details. At the end of the day,we have to generate a complete report on added and deleted files. Thats why ,we need a sequence. Also, we are thinking of referencing and sorting file id according to file type instead of long file names,which would speed up the search process

Comment: I get the use of the sequence, perfectly acceptable way to use it. The issue, as I see it, is trying to maintain some kind of gapless sequence. That's unnecessary. Be careful of the accepted answer approach for the reasons I stated above. Good luck.